# Meteor Multiple Field Find

Tags: meteor, collections, find

probably a simple fix for this, I have looked through the Meteor documentation and couldn't find an answer.

I'm trying to find through a collection and filter using multiple values.

In the application, there are 2 people in each conversation. I need to find if a conversation already exists between the 2 people.

```js
var convoexists =  Convo.find({
          $or: [{user_1: Meteor.user()._id},{user_2: userid}]
     }, { 
          $or: [{user_1: userid,{user_2: Meteor.user()._id}}]
     });
```

Comment: what did you expect this expression to do? did you read the documentation on `find`? what is that second argument supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first parameter to `.find()` is the query.
2. `$or` takes a matrix of objects as a value
3. `Meteor.user()._id` can be shortened to `Meteor.userId()`

ex:

```
var convoexists =  Convo.find({
  $or: [
    { user_1: Meteor.userId(), user_2: userid },
    { user_1: userid, user_2: Meteor.userId() }
  ]
 });
```